# То Intellij IDEA не показывает warnings на полосе прокрутки

Tags: intellij-idea, warning

Со светлой темой есть, а с темной - нет. Как сделать, чтобы были?

[image: Со светлой темой есть]
[image: а с темной - нет]

Comment: @ru51an, проверьте что во втором случае не включен "экономный" режим.